# Why are odd pages left pages?

Tags: margins, memoir, double-sided

I'm typesetting a friend's novel using LaTeX (in my actual document I'm using `memoir`, but the same happens if I just use `book`). It's possible I'm going crazy, but I'm sure that it's setting up odd pages to be left pages, instead of right pages (which is what appears to be standard). My code looks something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\mainmatter

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This generates me a 4 page PDF (you can download it [here](http://www.dominicrodger.com/test.pdf)) - which I *think* has odd pages as left-hand pages (odd pages have wide right margins, even pages have wide left margins, but then on the other hand, odd pages have page numbers on the right hand side, which makes them look like right-hand pages).

Shouldn't I have a wide left margin? Have I totally misunderstood odd and even pages? Have I just completely lost it from staring at this for too long?

Comment: **Odd** pages come on **right**. The **wider** margin is the **outer** one, so on page one, you should have a wide right margin. Is it so?

Comment: There’s a second caveat: The two-page-view of all PDF readers I know sets by default page 1 to the left and as result all odd pages, too. This can be changed, but the setting is in every reader in a different place and has a different name.

Comment: @Speravir -- `evince`, a popular document viewer for many GNU/Linux distributions leaves the first left/recto page alone on the right-hand side in its two-page viewing mode.  (I think it does this by default.)

Comment: @jon `hyperref` has an option somewhere to do the same in all readers ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Odd** pages come on **right**. The **wider** margin is the **outer** one, so on page one, you should have a wide right margin. So it seems to be correct.

The reason is that the outer margins should visually be the same as the "inner one", and the "inner one" is sum of the "inner margins" of both facing pages.

Comment: Ah - I thought they were to account for the fold of the book (sure there's a technical term for that - the fact that the inner margin isn't all visible). Thanks for the explanation! I guess I just need to bump up both inner and outer margins so that the inner content is still visible when the book is not fully opened).

Comment: @DominicRodger the inner margins (minus the binding correction) typically should together be as wide as an outer margin

Comment: @cgnieder - yup, got it. Thanks so much for the prompt and helpful explanations.

Comment: @DominicRodger Peter Wilson, the author of the `memoir` class, has written [_A Few Notes on Book Design_](http://texdoc.net/pkg/memdesign) which might be of interest for you.

Comment: Interestingly, the `amsbook` document class does not have this feature.  When using `amsbook`, the margins are symmetric.  Does anyone care to list which document classes have this feature and which ones don't?