# Page numbering and binding offset

Tags: margins, page-numbering, double-sided

I have a two-sided document with a few unnumbered introductory pages, and I want to start page numbering from 1 after these pages. To do that, I suppress page numbers with `\pagenumbering{gobble}`, and later start it with `\pagenumbering{arabic}`. However, this method screws up page numbering for things like `fancyhdr` and `geometry`'s `bindingoffset`. As to the headers, I can easily circumvent that by swapping around the headers for odd/even pages, but I see no way of making `bindingoffset` work with it.

Is there a way to make `bindingoffset` use global page numbers for the whole document instead of the counter that LaTeX uses for `\pagenumbering`? If not, is there a better way to suppress and later start page numbering without messing up `bindingoffset`?

Thank you.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[twoside, bindingoffset=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\lipsum[1-4]
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

I would like the second page (page number 1) to be correctly treated as a left page.

Comment: Be sure to add a `\cleardoublepage` *before* the `pagenumbering`-command. Also, be aware, that odd pages (1,3,5,...) are on right pages, even numbers (2,4,...) are on left pages.

Comment: @Johannes_B Oh, sorry, I should have been clearer about this - my first numbered page is a left page, so I basically want `bindingoffset` to work the other way round in my case. That is why I want it to use global page numbers, which would make my document's page 1 have page number 4, for example.

Comment: Can you show use some code in form of a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html)?

Comment: Also, please have a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87244/37907). You can also use package `showframe` to see exactly, what is on your page (the marginpars are of interest here).

Comment: @Johannes_B I have added a minimal working example.

Comment: Also, welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: And as already mentioned in my first comment, just add an `\cleardoublepage` before `\pagenumberin{}`

Comment: @Johannes_B Well, that just introduces an empty page, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a twosided document, you need to tell LaTeX not only to clear a single page (`\clearpage`), but to clear a double page if necessary (`\cleardoublepage`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[twoside, bindingoffset=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\lipsum[1-4]
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Please be aware, that an odd page in books is *always* on right handed pages, whereas even pages are on left handed pages. Using the book class, you could also use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`. There are historical reasons for that. But in modern times using computers to typeset, there is really no need for different paginations anymore.

Since an article usually is a short document, I advice you to channge the documentclass.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is a working solution, although I would also appreciate one where I can avoid having to add an empty page. Even if that means going against the 'rules' for page numbering.

Comment: @sps If you don't want to have an empty page, don't change page numbering. If you change page numbering, issue `\cleardoublepage` first. I wouldn't like to see your works come out strange and naughty just because you wish to save one page `:)`